# finding amount of memory usage of a command in bash

Tags: bash, python, java, c++, memory-usage

I wrote a program and now I need to measure it's performance so I use `time` to find timings but is there any command like time that I could run my program under it and have the amount of memory used by my program? (like what `time` does)

I'm programming in C/C++, java, python etc. so I need a uniform tool (like `time`) to measure memory usages.

TnX aLoT!

Comment: I'd suggest `ps`, `top` or `atop`

Comment: ps, top and atop can't be used if my program running time is 0.01 s I think! ;) so I want sth like time that measures the amount of memory for me and nothing else! emagine its command is memit, so I go running `memit ./a.out` just like `time ./a.out` to give the total amount of memory used. (just like `tiem ./a.out` that leaves me the total running time of my program)

Answer (score 1):

`ps`, `top`, and `atop` are not going to give you the most accurate answers. This [stack exchange topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/linux-how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process) addresses this in great detail and points to a [well-written blog entry](http://virtualthreads.blogspot.com/2006/02/understanding-memory-usage-on-linux.html) on the topic which details why this is the case.

There are better tools to help you try to quantify the memory usage, and `valgrind` [seems to be a good tool](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/valgrind/). You can install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install valgrind
```

Let's say you have a program called hello_world:

```
gcc -o hello_world -g hello_world.c
```

To get a heap profile for this program, you would run:

```
valgrind --tool=massif ./hello_world
```

This will give generic output to your screen, the actual results are saved to a file in that same directory that is in the form:

```
massif.out.pid
```

where pid is the program id for hello_world when you ran it in that instance.

It would probably be best to get the `time` information separately, i.e. don't try to run `valgrind` and `time` at the same time. The stackoverflow link provides other alternatives.

Comment: I told I need sth. like time as I could write in terminal `time ./a.out` and simply have running time of my program. I need a tool like this that leave me just the amount of memory usage of my program and nothing else! valgrind is so good tool but it's going too profile all memory actions of my program but I just need the total amount of memory used.